# dojo parser and registry issue

Tags: javascript, dojo

Please take a look to this embarassing snippet of code:

https://jsfiddle.net/nwatzos1/1/

### html

```
<div id="viewLogin" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View" data-dojo-props="selected:true">    
  <input id="txt" type="text" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox" data-dojo-props="selectOnClick:true, placeHolder:'pin'" name="pin" autocomplete="off" required>    
</div>
```

### js

```
require([
  "dijit/registry",
  "dojo/parser",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(registry, parser) {
    parser.parse();
  var text = registry.byId("txt");
  text.set("value", "hello");
});
```

### config

```
data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: false"
```

as you can see I get the error:

> TypeError: text is undefined

The same happens also if I set the `parseOnLoad` flag to `true` and comment the `parser.parse()` line.

I wait for the `domReady` then I parse it... why it cannot find the widgets?
To me, it seems very close to the first example in the Getting started documentation:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dojo_config/index.html

I'm not able to view my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo/domReady!` is a plugin that ensure that DOM is ready and events are loaded (delays the loading process until dom (event/domNodes) are loaded and this without using callback ) , resuming `dojo/domReady!` ensure `->` DOM loaded

`dojo/ready` is module that uses a callback function that unsure not only DOM is loaded ( because this last it self uses `dojo/domReady`) but also if all AMD modules in that block have to be loaded .  resuming `dojo/ready` ensure `->` DOM loaded + ensure AMD module inside the same block (require) parsed and loaded

When dom is Being loaded you're calling the `parser.parse();` and to parse the template modules and just above it you are trying to get refernce to your `dojox/mobile/TextBox` var `text = registry.byId("txt");` which will returns null beacause of the parser hasn't yet finish parsing and loading the module to the dojo registry .

So by Using `dojo/ready` you'll be ensure that the dom is being load and all widget parsed , see bellow sample :

```
require([
  "dijit/registry",
  "dojo/parser",
  "dojo/ready",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(registry, parser,ready) {

      parser.parse();
      ready(function(){
         var text = registry.byId("txt");
         console.log(text);
        text.set("value", "hello");
      })
});
```

[Here is Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwatzos1/2/)

Comment: From here: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/ready.html, I understand it should be enough to use the plugin (`dojo/domReady!`) if I don't need to set a priority queue. And most examples I've seen rely only on the plugin. Where are the difference with my code?

Comment: Hey @Mark after lokking forward ,  I've added explanation that show you why you get that error when using  `dojo/domReady!`

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use `parser.parse().then(...)` to ensure parser has completed its task.

```js
require([
  "dijit/registry",
  "dojo/parser",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(registry, parser) {
       parser.parse().then(function(){
       var text = registry.byId("txt");
       text.set("value", "hello");
       });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="viewLogin" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
  <input id="txt" type="text" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox" data-dojo-props="selectOnClick:true, placeHolder:'pin'" name="pin" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually works, but I've never seen such a use in dojo tutorials. They just wait for `domReady!`. Have you an explanation?

Comment: I have several html and js sections, one for each view. I know the parser should run only once, but how to keep waiting all js functions? For clarity and easy maintenance I don't want to have only one huge js function...

Comment: The parser returns a promise when it has to handle loading widgets itself. In the above example, View and TextBox aren't loaded before `parse` is called, so the parser will have to load them itself (which is an async process).